# Как включить автоотступы в notepad++ для html?

Tags: html, notepad++, ide

Как включить автоотступы в notepad++ для html?

Comment: Что значит автоотступы, вы имеете введу автотабуляцию чтоле?

Comment: Да, я имею виду автотабуляцию.

Comment: так они появляются автоматически при выборе синтаксиса...а уровнем вложенности можно управлять самому Tab'ом или пробелом...заданный отступ автоматически будет применяться....

Comment: поставить тип документа в notepad++ - html

Comment: Я думал авто имел введу - подстановку **дополнительного** символа табуляции, но, видимо, ошибся...

Answer (score 2):

Если не ошибаюсь этот функционал несет модуль Notepad#, идем в plugin manager, находим, устанавливаем.

Или у вы имели введу все-таки выравнивание каретки?

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, лучшим решением будет "Синтаксис" -> "HTML". В этом случае будет сохраняться установленные отступы + подсветка кода.

Answer (score 1):

В notepad++ есть баг, кода нажимаешь ентер, оно каретку ингода не переносить правильно, а скидывает в начало строки

Comment: С третьей версии пользуюсь - не было такого.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы использовать функцию "Автоотступы" нужно установить плагин для требуемого языка и найти в нем строку со словом *indent* или *autoindent*. Для html я пока не нашел такого плагина(может подойти XML tools для XML),а для С-подобных языков - NppAutoIndent.

Answer (score 1):

Вид -> Перенос строк

Answer (score 0):

Нужно установить плагин Indent by Fold (Плагины - Управление Плагинами...). Далее нажимаем Плагины - Indent by Fold - Reindent File. Все готово, радуемся жизни).

Answer (score -1):

Для Notepad++ существует плагин Tidy2: https://code.google.com/p/npp-tidy2/downloads/list

Там есть разные виды форматирования. При вводе текста автоматически выставляются все табуляции и переносы.